# Add Counter to header line at end of string using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to add a "page number" with the format ### to the end of each header line in my file. The Header lines are always the same constant, but appear at random intervals throughout the document. I have attempted this using SED and AWK, but am open to all suggestions. I tried the following sudo code tailored for my issue

```
counter=0
max = find number of Header Line string
while reading 
       for (i =0; i< Pagemax;i++)
{
replace string Header Line with page counter
counter+1
}
```

Below is a hypothetical input/output for what needs to be accomplished.

Input Example:

```
Header Line     
Dolphin
Whale
Fish
Header Line     
Bird
Header Line     
Bus
Skate Board
Bike
```

Desired Output:

```
Header Line     001
Dolphin
Whale
Fish
Header Line     002
Bird
Header Line     003
Bus
Skate Board
Bike
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '/Header Line/ { $0 = $0 sprintf("\t%03d", ++n) } 1' filename
```

The code is quite simple:

```
/Header Line/ {                   # when a header line is found
  $0 = $0 sprintf("\t%03d", ++n)  # increase the counter n and append a tab
                                  # followed by it (formatted appropriately)
                                  # to the line
}
1                                 # then print (non-header lines will be
                                  # printed unchanged)
```

Comment: Might be better to use `print $0, sprintf(...); next` to use `OFS` but I don't know what the OP wants exactly.

Comment: I think I'd prefer `$0 = $0 OFS sprintf("%03d", ++n)`, but I agree that it could be an improvement if the script grows more complex.

Comment: FWIW I'd use `$0 = sprintf("%s%s%03d", $0, OFS, ++n)` instead of a sprintf plus a concatenation but nbd...